What is the level of tracking in a Progressive Web App (PWA)?
Scenario: You log into Twitter in a mobile Safari Private Browsing tab with Advanced Tracking and Fingerprinting Protection enabled, then create a PWA (i.e., Add to Home Screen) of the private tab.
Does the website have the same ability to track us in a PWA as from a tab in Safari? Is the PWA instance sandboxed from Safari? Is the PWA created in a Private Browsing instance?
Observations: The PWA is a standalone instance that can be forced closed independently of Safari and force closing the PWA does not log you out of the site like closing a Private Browsing tab does.

If this gets closed, please edit it down to one and only one question. Have you found any Apple documentation that helps define what privacy means in the context of your problem?
